# Python imports don't work on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-import

Im trying to import a variable from another file. The problem is I get a `ImportError: cannot import name 'issues'` on line 6 in variables.py
The strange thing is, this works just fine on my ubuntu laptop but not on my windows main computer. I've googled a bit and apparently it has something to do with relative paths, so I've tried adding a . in front of parser, but then it gives the error `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`.
Any idea whats causing this?

parser.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

## Settings
fileIn = 'trending_today.in'
fileOut = 'trending_today.out'

print("Parse file...", end=" ")

## Parse file
with open(fileIn) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]

## Parse lines
issues = []
for i in range(len(content)):
    issues.append(content[i].split(' '))

for i in range(len(issues)):
    for j in range(len(issues[i])):
        issues[i][j] = int(issues[i][j])

print("done.")

## Functions for writing
def writeFile(commands):    # Input [[]]
    print("Write output file...", end=" ")
    for i in range(len(commands)):
        writeLine(commands[i])
    print("done.")
    return

def writeLine(line):    # Input: []
    string = ' '.join(line) # Convert array to line
    f = open(fileOut, 'a')
    f.write(string + '\n')
    f.close()
    return
```

variables.py (which I execute):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

## Import parser
from .parser import issues

print("Setup variables...", end=" ")

## Settings
number_videos = issues[0][0]
number_endpoints = issues[0][1]
number_request_decs = issues[0][2]
number_caches = issues[0][3]
cache_capacity = issues[0][4]

videos = issues[1]  # Size of videos

## Endpoints
endpoints = []  # 0 = datacenter ms
                # 1 = [ [cache_nr, cache_ms] ]
c = 2
for i in range(number_endpoints):
    ep = issues[c]
    endpoints.append([])
    endpoints[i].append(ep[0])
    endpoints[i].append([])
    for j in range(ep[1]):
        cache = issues[c+j+1]
        endpoints[i][1].append(cache)
    c += ep[1]
    c += 1

requests = []   # 0 = Video
                # 1 = Endpoint
                # 2 = Requests
for i in range(number_request_decs):
    requests.append(issues[c+i])

print("done.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whrn you run you program, does it print "`Parsing file... done.`", before reporting the error, or just "`Parsing file...`"?

If it prints the second message, I suspect that the issues is that the file "`trending_today.in`" is not in the current working directory, and the `open()` is failing with an exception, which means the import gets aborted before `issues` gets set.

You will either need to change your working directory to the appropriate location, or ensure that the file is there.

======

Since neither of the outputs are appearing, the script is picking up the parser module in the standard library, rather than the local one.

Either rename "`parser.py`" to something that is not part of the library, or set PYTHONPATH to either "`.`" or the name of the directory. I suspect on the unix version, PYTHONPATH is already set.

Adding a "`__init__.py`" file may also work.

Comment: Something along these lines was my thought as well, but when I run parser.py by itself it works and displays "Parsing file... done." correctly. Adding to that, printing something like issues[0] also works, so issues is definetly not the problem.

Comment: When you run the main program, do you get the "parsing .. done" message, part of it, or none of it?

Comment: Hmm I get none of it

Comment: try creating "dummy.py", which consists of "import parser;print (parser.__file__)", and see what the output is. Maybe it's picking uup the wrong parser.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'` is the result

Comment: Try "import parser; print (dir(parser))", and let me know the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136706/discussion-between-simon-callan-and-nn3112337).

Comment: for anyone browsing: it was the name of parser, renaming it solves it.

Comment: Please remove the suggestion to add the current directory (i.e. ".") to `PYTHONPATH`.  Python prepends the script directory to `sys.path`. It only prepends the current directory for the interactive REPL. Adding it for scripts is a bad idea. BTW, the difference between Ubuntu and Windows in this case is that the DLL on Windows has more built-in modules than the executable on Ubuntu, including the `parser` module. Check `sys.builtin_module_names`. Since `parser` is an extension module in the standard library on Ubuntu, a "parser.py" file in the script directory takes precedence.